# Universal Windows Platform - CustomHidDevice (Error: Value is blocked)

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, hid

I am using Universal Windows Platform sample
[CustomHidDeviceAcess](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomHidDeviceAccess) to connect with Mouse with HID support.
But then I am getting the following error during 'Build'.

> DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. The Appx package's manifest is invalid.: Cannot register package Microsoft.SDKSamples.CustomHidDeviceAccess.CPP because of a problem with Function element usage:0001 0002: Value is blocked, and not allowed on this bus (0x80073cf6)

The usage page and id for this mouse is 0001 and 0002, which is causing this error.
Originally this sample application is using the following usage page and id to connect with SuperMutt device:

```
 <!--SuperMutt Device-->
  <Device Id="vidpid:045E 0610">
    <Function Type="usage:FFAA 0001" />
  </Device>
```

My first question: is it possible to fix the error that I get?

According to reference in MSDN, there is [Limitations of the HID API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182882.aspx) which I assume this is one of them. So my next question: what is the alternative?

I have tried using **SetupDiGetClassDevs** method to open HID Collection, but it seems that UWP isn't part of **#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)**, cause it was disabled when I open the SetupAPI.h, does anyone can explain how to setup or enable this?

Appreciate the help..

Answer (score 0):

> DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. The Appx package's manifest is invalid.: Cannot register package Microsoft.SDKSamples.CustomHidDeviceAccess.CPP because of a problem with Function element usage:0001 0002: Value is blocked, and not allowed on this bus (0x80073cf6)

The exception has explained the reason, the capability is blocked per [the article you mentioned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182882.aspx#limitations_of_the_hid_api)

There is no alternative way in the present, I would forward to your feedback to the related team.

Comment: I tried to use CreateFile2() as alternative way to access the HID device. But it doesn't give access to the device, as mentioned in this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5d76ee7d-c560-443d-988a-5c3d3acd4275/using-createfile2-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop, and now I am trying to use DeviceIoControl

Comment: The DeviceIoControl sample is using Serial, is there sample with USB HID device? Thanks in advance! https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/deviceiocontroller

Comment: @undo no such sample for USB HID device, you may create an issue in [here](https://github.com/ms-iot/content/issues) or I can help you to submit this request on your behalf.

Comment: Hi Franklin, please help to submit this request. Thank you.

Comment: may I know how long is this gonna take?

Comment: @undo Not sure, the related team needs to handle bunch of requests. If you are urgent, please consider opening a support ticket to get 1:1 tech support